# Why does my formula show #VALUE! when I used a variable in "LET" function, but when I referenced outside it doesn't break, both have the same formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I used the variable `based_on_timetable` in the `LET` function it return `#VALUE!`, but when I referenced `H9#` it works? Both have the same formula.

`#VALUE!` problem
1st picture showing error when I used a variable in `LET`:

[image: 1st picture showing error when I used a variable in LET]

The second picture is the result I want. When I referenced outside of the `LET` function `H9#`:

[image: 2nd Picture result I'm looking for]

Both have the same formula `H9#` and `based_on_timetable` in `LET` function:

[image: 3rd Picture both have the same formula]

Looking to get the result in the second picture so 1,1,1,1. But I want to do it inside of the `LET` function instead of referencing outside of the `LET` function.

Comment: That's normal behavior. `COUNTIF` doesn't work with arrays, only with ranges. You need to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

### Count Matches

```
=LET(
    tt,FILTER(C4:C7,H4:H7="R"),
    tr,D2:G2,
MAP(tr,LAMBDA(r,COUNT(XMATCH(tt,r)))))
```

Comment: I usually implement MMULT in such case, but this is clever and easier to write. The benefit of MMULT is that you can have multiple conditions.